# Stuck with Go concurrency

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I can't seem to figure out what to do next. My goal is to create an array of all the sub images from the original image using the SubImage function from the image package. I am able to partition an image in the imageSplit() function and pass to imageReceiver() function via a channel.

I actually receive the data in function imageReceiver(), but I don't know how to append to an array and use it after receiving all the images from imageSplit() function.

```
// Partitions Image
func Partition(src image.Image) []image.Image {

    newImg := image.NewNRGBA64(src.Bounds())

    r := newImg.Rect
    dx, dy := r.Dx(), r.Dy()

   // partitionNum
   pNum := 3

    // partition x
    px, py := (dx / pNum), (dy / pNum)

    imgChan := make(chan image.Image)
    imgStorage := make([]image.Image, 0)

    for i := 1; i < pNum; i++ {
        for j := 1; j < pNum; j++ {
            startX, startY := ((px * i) - px), ((py * j) - py)
            endX, endY := (px * i), (py * j)

            go imageSplit(imgChan, newImg, startX, startY, endX, endY)
            go imageReceiver(imgChan)
        }
    }

    return imgStorage

}

// Creates sub-images of img
func imageSplit(imgChan chan image.Image, img *image.NRGBA64, startX, startY, endX, endY int) {
    r := image.Rect(startX, startY, endX, endY)
    subImg := img.SubImage(r)

    imgChan <- subImg
}

// Receive sub-image from channel
func imageReceiver(imgChan chan image.Image) {
    img := <-imgChan
    spew.Dump(img.Bounds())
}
```

I thought of creating a global array of image.Image but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to "save" all the sub images.

I guess the reason this is a bit confusing is because this is the first time I'm working with concurrency in Go.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You'd want a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) so that `Partition` doesn't return until the goroutines finish or just a second for loop reading in the `pNum` results and appending right in `Partition`. But I don't see the point of using goroutines here, `SubImage` is usually quite fast as it normally only creates a new image object that shares the pixel data from the existing image (i.e. there is usually no data copying, just some bookkeeping).

Comment: Thanks but I was having issues with understanding how to create an array of image.Image after my imageReceiver() function... @evanmcdonnal gave an answer that pertained to my problem.  Thanks for the side note with the SubImage function... I am very new to concurrency with Go so figured this would be a perfect way to simultaneously create goroutines to split my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for how you can do this but I would say your basic problem is that your receiver doesn't do aggregation and if you changed it so it did it would not be thread safe.

The simple choice to modify your receiver to do aggregation would be to allocate an `Image` array before the loop and pass a pointer to it into the receiver method which would then just use append when it reads of the channel. But then you would have a bunch of different goroutines fighting for access to the same array. So really, you don't want the aggregation to be multithreaded. If it is you need a locking mechanism in order to write to the collection.

Instead you want to block after the loop. The simplest way to do that would just be to put the body of your receiver right there inline after the loop like;

```
imgs := []image.Image{}
img := <-imgChan
imgs = append(imgs, img)
spew.Dump(img.Bounds())
```

The problem is in the real world then your software would block on that line and be unresponsive (have no way of dying or exiting or anything) so instead you'd typically use a channel select where you have at least 2 channels/cases, an abort channel that the caller of `Partition` can use to kill it if it needs to exit and the case that receives from `imgChan`. That would look a little more like this;

```
imgs := []image.Image{}

select {
    case img := <-imgChan
         imgs = append(imgs, img)
         spew.Dump(img.Bounds())
    case _ := <-abortChan:
        return MyCustomError();
    }
```

Which make it so your aggregation is not concurrent, only the work to produce the results which I personally think is the better design. I could explain how to lock in your receiver method as well but I'm sure you can find plenty of examples of mutex's ect.

Comment: Sweet this worked, I was having trouble wrapping my head around getting the data after my receiver function... I was planning on passing a []image.Image pointer to the receiver function but yes like you said, would have different goroutines fighting for access to the same array.  Thanks the select statement worked for me onto the real challege hehe